# Inserir imagem de outra pasta em iframe php

Tags: php, iframe

Um *webapp* de chamados. A pessoa vai abrir o chamado e tem a opção de tirar uma foto como evidência. Essa foto vai ser enviada para o servidor e seu caminho armazenado no banco e na variável `$destino` em `recebeUpload.php` e preciso colocar um *iframe* em `modalVisualizar.php` para exibir uma imagem que a variável armazena. Este PHP está dentro de `modalVisualizar.php`.

```
<?php
            $destino = $_GET['destino'];
            $s = 
                '<iframe img src="/APIChamados/img/?destino=' .$destino. '" name="mostraEvidencia"></iframe>';
            echo $s;
        ?>
```

Comment: E qual é a relação entre os arquivos `recebeUpload.php` e `modalVisualizar.php`? Um depende do outro, um inclui o outro ou o quê? Se são independentes, a sua variável não existirá em `modalVisualizar.php`.

Comment: Eita...vai funcionar assim:
recebeUpload.php vai receber as imagens de evidência do chamado.
Em modalVisualizar.php, o admin visualiza o chamado com as imagens (3 imagens no máximo).
Então sim, são independentes.
Existe uma maneira de popular este iframe com a informação da variável?

PS,: Obrigado pela edição, sou novo aqui e não sei editar direito ainda.

Comment: Você diz que os caminhos ficarão armazenados no banco, então basta buscar no banco ao invés de usar direto da variável.

Comment: Certo, mas pra cada imagem ele gera um ID diferente. Por isso estava querendo pegar pela variável. Vou tentar aqui.

Comment: Não foi, ele não volta a imagem.
Aparece o iframe, mas não mostra a imagem.